# How can I winterize windows with original trim from 1885 without ruining them?

Tags: windows, winterizing

I have very nice wood trim and would rather not use the double sided tape on them. I have tried in the past on one window and it took some of the trim off with it.  I really don't want to ruin the trim but would also like to put plastic on it.  The windows need to be replaced eventually but my cash flow right now it's not possible.  I know that would help because the windows are the original from when the house was built in 1885.

Is there another way to winterize windows that will not ruin my trim?  I can't put plastic on the outside, its all metal, and I have tried to put it on the inside of the trim of the window instead of around the window.  I have tried everything I can possible think of to try and NOT ruin this beautiful trim. Are there any suggestions for me that wont break the bank?

Comment: painted or clear finish on the trim?

Comment: picture?  we love pictures, especially of what you say got damaged.

Comment: The guy I shared a house with that used plastic film religiously bought the cheapest film kit he could find, tossed the tape, and bought 3M tape (cheaper than buying 3M's kit) - we never had a problem with THAT tape coming off cleanly.

Comment: Also, please consider repairing those windows instead of replacing, when that time comes. There's tons of info online on restoring and weatherizing old windows. Properly restored old window with a storm will be pretty much as efficient as any new vinyl crap.

Answer (score 1):

You could fabricate a removable wooden frame that can be covered with the light plastic film. You could also use aluminum storm window framing but it may be cost prohibitive Make the frame slightly smaller than dimensions of the trimmed window opening. Cover the edges of the frame with weather strip to form a seal against the trim and to protect it from being scratched by the frame. Your window openings may no longer be square so each frame may be a custom fit to a specific window.